# Umbraco c# year creator

Tags: c#, html, umbraco

I'm looking to create a auto year bit of code, which will save anyone going into the system every year to change the copyright date from 2013 to 2014, does anyone know of any code that does this?

Comment: Would not Javascript be a better solution? `new Date().getYear() + 1900`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (in a Razor view, available from v4.6)

```
@DateTime.Now.Year
```

If you are using older master pages, you can use this:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.Year %>
```